# Ubuntu 10 dependencies not met

Tags: gtk, ubuntu-10.10, dependencies

I'm getting this error when trying to do an install and build (Ubuntu 10.10):

```
 checking for DEPENDENCIES... configure: error: Package requirements (
     gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10.0
      pygtk-2.0
      x11
  ) were not met:

  No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

  Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
  installed software in a non-standard prefix.

  Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
  and DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
  See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I've tried pointing `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` both to `pkg-config` and to the directory that holds all of the .pc files (`/usr/share/pkg-config`).  The man page for `pkg-config` doesn't mention `DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS` or `DEPENDENCIES_LIBS`.  I'm at a bit of a loss.  I've tried using aptitude to install everything I could find which involved the letters "gtk" to no avail.

Any suggestions?  I would really prefer to use `aptitude`, `apt-get` or `dpkg` to solve this if at all possible.  I haven't tried rebuilding those packages from source.

Comment: What're you trying to build ?

Comment: I've been having difficulties with my Guake install, so I was hoping to install from source so that I could (possibly) debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want

```
apt-get build-dep guake
```

This installs all the packages you need to compile `guake`. Then you can do

```
apt-get source guake
cd guake-*/
# edit, patch, ...
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc -b -nc
```

Comment: That worked like a champ.  I will up-vote this when I get the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of this command?

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep pygtk
```

How about the same for x11?

It looks sort of as if you're trying to install a package that wants x11 when you have xorg installed, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. There's no direct relationship between Debian/Ubuntu package names and `pkg-config` names. And xorg is the implementation of x11 on Ubuntu and just about everywhere.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | grep gtk` says I have `python-gtk2` which is, as best as I can tell, the most current descendant.  But, `apt-get build-dep guake` worked.  Thanks.